# Create sub-dictionary from dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Function criarB return:

```
{269476: 200129, 209624: 200129 ...}
 200129 position in aux2, '200129 and 209624 are keys'
```

How to split dict according to keys, if keys % 10 = 0 must be stored in list[0]

```
list = [[], [], ...]
```

Class complete:

```
class Buckets:

def __init__(self, keys, palavras, tamanhoP):
    self.listaBuckts = dict()
    self.listaHash = list()
    self.keys = list(keys)

    aux = list(zip(keys, palavras))
    self.aux2 = list()

    for i in range(0, len(aux), tamanhoP):
        self.aux2.append(dict(aux[i:i + tamanhoP]))

def criarB(self):
    for i, pag in enumerate(self.aux2):
        for v in pag.keys():
            self.listaBuckts[v] = i
    return self.listaBuckts

def indexar(self):
    count = 0
    buckets = [[] for _ in range(10)]

    for r in range(0, len(buckets)):
        for s in range(0, len(self.listaBuckts)):
            if s % 3 == 0:
                buckets[r].append([v + count for v in self.listaHash[s:s + 3]])
        count += 1
    return buckets[0]
```

the "indexing" function uses a list that contains only indexes, how do I use the keys of the self.buckets dict and divide the dict according to the function

Attempt:

```
class Buckets:

def __init__(self, keys, palavras, tamanhoP):
    self.listaBuckts = dict()
    self.listaHash = list()
    self.keys = list(keys)

    aux = list(zip(keys, palavras))
    self.aux2 = list()

    for i in range(0, len(aux), tamanhoP):
        self.aux2.append(dict(aux[i:i + tamanhoP]))

def criarB(self):
    for i, pag in enumerate(self.aux2):
        for v in pag.keys():
            self.listaBuckts[v] = i
    return self.listaBuckts

def indexar(self):
    test = [[] for _ in range(10)]

    for x in self.listaBuckts:
        i = x % 10
        test[i].append([x, dict[x]])
    return test[0]
```

Comment: What means "list[0]" here? Edit the question to show what you tried, its output or error message and the expected output.

Comment: I don't see a class here or any running code. Please post a [mre] that is proper runnable code

Comment: edited question

Comment: (1) You shouldn't use names of the standard library (as "dict") as variable names. (2) Your last line defines "dict" as a set of empty dictionaries, this doesn't make sense. "dict{0}" is syntactically incorrect and doesn't make sense either.

Comment: I quoted dict why I found it easier to understand, but it really would be a list, I put the method in question, I believe it is easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
listOfDicts = [{k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if k%10==i} for i in range(10)]
```

or a loop:

```
listOfDicts = [ dict() for _ in range(10) ]
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    listOfDicts[key%10].update({key:value})
```

Comment: Perfect answer, but what if I want to divide the sublists into equal slices? example: listOfDict [0] = {{x, y, z}, {w, a, t}, {e}}

Comment: Not sure what you mean by equal slice given the example you have in your comment.  Do you mean to have equal size dictionaries in each slot ?  If so, how would you figure which slot will contain a given key afterward ?  Perhaps this should be the topic of a separate question in SO.

Comment: YesI created a new one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470709/como-quebrar-sub-listas-em-um-dict

Comment: I would have made the innermost line of your loop be `listOfDicts[key%10][key]=value`, which does the same thing but should be slightly faster since it avoids constructing a new `{key:value}` dictionary and avoids making a needless `update()` function call.  The only real drawback is that the adjacent brackets may be confusing, but they're actually quite intuitive, meaning: from our list of dicts get the dictionary at index`[key%10]` and then in that dictionary set key `[key]` equal to `value`.

Comment: @JustinFisher, I agree, that would indeed be better. I answered that question a while ago and I don't remember why I dit it with an update, given that the source guarantees that there will be no duplicate keys .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the dictionary into two lists based on keys. I think the follow can work

```python
dict #The dictionary returned from function crairB
a = [] #List to save keys and values for key%10==0
b = [] #List for key%10!=0
for x in dict:
    if x%10==0:
        a.append([x,dict[x]]) #Here I have saved both keys and values in the list, you can edit according to your need.
    else:
        b.append([x,dict[x]])
```

Edit:

If you have to split the data into 2D list with rows equal to keys % 10, then I think the following can work.

```python
list = [[] for _ in range(10)]

for x in dict:
    i = x%10
    list[i].append([x,dict[x]])
```

Comment: whats what is the variable "d" ?

Comment: It's the dictionary dict. My mistake. Edited.

Comment: that's right, but could you adapt the answer to the last code I edited in the question? def indexar

Comment: what is the variable "k" ? 10 ?

Comment: Yeah it's 10. Does the list give you required answer?

Comment: unfortunately not, it returns an empty list

Comment: Can you edit your final code. Then we can find an error somewhere.

Comment: Edited ! Pls take a look

Comment: Sorry I have to sleep now. I will try to figure it out as soon as I can