# How to break sub lists into a dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Well guys, I created a dict, and divided it using the function:

```
listOfDicts = [{k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if k%10==i} for i in range(10)]
```

From that, I got 10 sublists:

```
listOfDicts[0 a 9]
listOfDict[0]: {0: 0, 10: 5, 20: 10, 30: 15, 40: 20, 50: 25, 60: 30, 70: 35, 80: 40, 90: 45}
```

But what if I want to divide the sublists into equal sizes (in the case size = 3) and add in a single dict:

```
listOfDict[0]: {{0: 0, 10: 5, 20: 10}, {30: 15, 40: 20, 50: 25}, {60: 30, 70: 35, 80: 40}, {90: 45}}
```

Comment: Please search on "Python chunk list" for a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives depending on what you are looking for:

```
dictionary = {0: 123, 10: 345, 20: 678, 30: 123, 40: 345, 50: 678, 60: 123, 70: 345, 80: 678 ,90: 123 }
```

1) Fixed number of slots in list (i.e. always 10):

```
slotCount   = len(dictionary)//10
items       = sorted(dictionary.items())
listOfDict  = [ dict(items[i:i+ slotCount]) 
                for i in range(0,len(items),slotCount) ]
listOfDict += [ {} for _ in range(slotCount,len(items),-1) ]
```

2) Fixed number of entries per slots (variable number of slots):

```
bucketSize  = 10
items       = sorted(dictionary.items())
listOfDict  = [ dict(items[i:i+bucketSize]) 
                for i in range(0,len(items),bucketSize) ]
```

3) Balanced number of entries and slots:

```
bucketSize  = int(len(dictionary)**0.5)
items       = sorted(dictionary.items())
listOfDict  = [ dict(items[i:i+bucketSize]) 
                for i in range(0,len(items),bucketSize) ]
```

4) Evenly distributed data over the 10 slots in the list:

```
slotCount   = 10
listOfDicts = [ {k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() 
                    if abs(hash(str(k))) % slotCount == i} 
                for i in range(slotCount) ]
```

*Note: all these methods will allow for a way to determine which slot a key belongs to after creating the list.  The first 3 approaches break down the dictionary in sorted order of the key so a bisecting search algorithm can be used.  The 4th simply uses a hashing function which directly returns the key's slot number*

Comment: Alain, but what if I want to share the sublist of listOfDics ? into equal size, ex: 3

Comment: Methods #2 allows you to specify a fixed size (simply assign 3 to bucketSize).

Comment: Method 4 returns 10 sublist, ok? but if I want to subdivide the sublist into pieces, not the original dict

Comment: You should describe what you are looking for in your question with an expected output that corresponds to all your "'what if" conditions.  It would avoid carpet bombing answers that try to cover all the possible alternatives (like I just did in this answer).  perhaps thinking your problem through a little bit more would help you find the solution based on these answers (or at least ask a more focused question).

Comment: take a look at the question, there was the expected exit

Comment: all 4 methods only return a list with 10 sublists, but if I want to divide these sublists into equal pieces

Comment: Methods #2 and #3 will return a variable list size with equal number of items in the dictionary in each slot (except prehaps the last slot depending on the size of the original dictionary).

Comment: I reformulated the question, take a look if it helps